# WebApi 2 download file with httpResponseMessage return unauthorized 401

Tags: c#, web-config, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, httpresponsemessage

hello I want to download pdf files from web api.

**In  the first, I  Use Identity Token Based (with authorized api) and OWIN**

```
var file1 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(file1);
response.Content.Headers.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileModel.Name;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
return response;
```

when I want to download this file, my download manager ask for username and password.

This issue only occurred in one of my projects, but works well in other my projects.

[image: download manager error]

Comment: The code you posted so far worked well in IIS Express. May be the difference is in your web.config and that's why it works in some projects and not in others, but I don't know. Have you tried adding `[AllowAnonymous]` ?

Comment: yes, I try with [AllowAnonymous] but not working on this project. I guess my web.config is faulty. I use this code in a new web api project and works fine